# ddwrt client brigde acces point lost

Tags: router, wifi

Ok I have an AP with ddwrt firm (i know its not the best, but continue reading!)

AP is configured to work like a wifi "transparent" brigde, also it had a virtual wifi network card to expand radius of wifi signal in that same AP.
The brigde is working, computers behind AP gets ips from main routers which shares internet....BUT! I cant access webgui of the bridge AP...

Main problem : AP is lost, but its working as brigde. I cant find it in the network (it didnt have any ip!) so I cant change any configuration...

First solution : Reset AP, but it cannot be done. Reset button dont works due to a bug in ddwrt micro firm that mi linksys WAP54g had installed (I really hate this firmware I like more openwrt that my main router has)

Second Solution : arp -a from main router , from computers behind AP...It dont appears in the list.

Any more ideas, the router at some level must be there, the brigde is working.

I know its possible that the AP is with an ip like 192.168.100.2 , my subnect actually is 172.16.X.X.

:) thanks!

Comment: Wow, good luck with that. I've done a similar thing with DDWRT in the past (actually I was stealing my neighbours internet) but in my scenario it kept its IP address...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem with the pin 15 and pin 16 of the flash chip, this causes an crc error, and the ap becames in mode to allow tftpd upload of new image.

Comment: the access point was at level 2, so no way to access configuration.
Reset button wasnt working.